# WPF animation idea for flipping a page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, animation

I need an idea how to do the following animation idea. Lets assume I have a view model defined as such:

```
public interface IMyViewModel
{
   IPage CurrentPage { get; set;}
}

public interface IPage
{
   string Title { get; set; }
   string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The `IPage` object is, plainly spoken, a piece of paper with the title and the description written on it. When the `IPage` object changes in my view model I want to have an animation as outlined below:
[image: animation outline]

The paper should spin 180°. At the stage when it spun 90° I need to update the shown content.

Is that possible with my view models? Are there any nice WPF tricks for that?

Comment: That's not something you would do in a viewmodel. It's something you would do in the view. [This page provides example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.viewport2dvisual3d(v=vs.110).aspx) demonstrating how to do a trapezoidal transform in XAML. What you need to do then is have two of those superimposed, with Triggers driving their visibility. In an EnterAction when they become visible, you animate the AxisAngleRotation3D.Angle property from 180 down to 0; on their ExitAction for visibility, you rotate the opposite way. Then you have to...

Comment: ...synchronize it all. I wouldn't touch it with a stick, but it's doable. Also, maybe I'm thinking about the mechanics in a completely wrong way. But from 50,000 ft, that `Viewport3D` thing can give you the geometry transform you need, and triggers and DoubleAnimation can animate it. Maybe you want VisualState instead of triggers.

Comment: This an interesting class. I think the hard part will be how to delay the synchronization until it flipped 90° and still having a smooth animation. Maybe I could somehow synchronize the new `IPage` before the animation starts with the backside of the 3D object which I then rotate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kind of old but still somewhat cool: [Avalon Patient Monitoring](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Healthcare-Prototype-9f94f5a7#content). You may want to look at `Rotater3DTransition.xaml` and `Flipper3DTransition.xaml`.

[image]

Comment: This gave me the idea how to synchronize before the animation. in `Flipper3DTransition` they set the backside of the plane before they start the animation.